# capacitive touch screens not responding

Tags: touchscreen

I have several old cellphones that stopped accepting any touch input.... there has been no water damage and have not been dropped since they did work. they just sat for a while.

first I wonder as this is called capacitive does that mean maybe a capacitor is responsible and it may have discharged over time, if this is the case is there a way to recharge it?

second is there any way to repair something like this cheaply.

third is this normal that touch screens simply go bad from not being used?

Answer (score 0):

Old Mobile Phones having such problem but none user consider the fact that capacitive displays can be controlled with very light touches of a finger and generally cannot be used with wet or gloved hand.

also, just Read about Capacitive sensing from this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing). You will get idea about Surface and Projected capacitance.

and some mobiles with this technologies stop working or not responding to touch. that was just e-waste though you can open device and learn many things.

Comment: it is a bit of a nuicanse to think these phones will be sent to be garbage when the display works and the motherboard works but the single sensor setup for input has gone bad...

Comment: But Changing those particular sensor will cost you more. or you can buy new one with exchange of old one.